# How to compare and select values from string using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Had a class:

```
 class filedate
 {
      public int id;
      public string fname;
 }
```

Fill my list with values:

```
 List<filedate> List = ReadList(sqlFiles);
 string[] FolderFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path2Copy);
```

Trying to get results:

```
  var results = List.Where(filedate =>
        FolderFiles.Any(x=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) ==             
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filedate.fname)));
```

I have the same files in `List` and `FolderFiles`, but get no results in `results`. I am a newbie to Linq. Where is the problem?

**update:**
List: (count) > 1000
for example:
<1023, 'tr_F2opervag_2808_1644.dat'>

FolderFiles example:
"\\domain.corp.dns\share\folder\tr_F2opervag_2808_1644.dat"

**Update 2**:
found out my mistake! Comment with intersection was helpful! This code is working:

```
  var results = List.Where(
            (filedate x) =>
            {
                return ! FolderFiles.Any(xxx =>
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xxx) ==
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.fname));
            });
```

Comment: Have you heard of `System.IO.FileInfo`? [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Comment: Your code seems correct, would you show sample input?

Comment: What do you do with results? Do you loop over it? Do you store it in a list or array?

Comment: `==` operator compares strings case-sensitively. Are the cases for corresponding names the same?

Comment: Probably the problem is in the string comparison.  Do the file names have the same case, for example?  Use the debugger.

Comment: I need to find out, what files, which are in DB, are not in folder. I dont need FileInfo. Cases are the same.

Comment: Your IDE is punishing you for using uppercase on the first letter of your declared variable names. :P

Comment: It is not my files, i load them from Exchange =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code works fine for me so there's something wrong with the format of your data in the List coming back from the database.

Post an example of an `fname` value from the filedata object. It needs to be a valid fully qualified path.

This works fine for me.

```
public class FileData{
    public int id;
    public string fname;
}
void Main()
{
    List<FileData> list = new List<FileData>{
        new FileData { id=1, fname="C:\\install.res.1042.dll"},
        new FileData { id=2, fname="C:\\install.res.1041.dll" },
        new FileData { id=3, fname="C:\\install.res.9999.dll"}
    };

    string[] FolderFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\");

    var results = list
        .Where(fd => 
            FolderFiles.Any(x=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) ==             
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fd.fname)));

    Console.WriteLine(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the difference this should work. This is available via [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

```
var dbFiles = ReadList(sqlFiles);

var dbFilePaths =
    dbFiles.Select(fdate => 
       Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fdate.fname).ToLower());

var fsFilePaths =
    Directory
    .GetFiles(path2Copy)
    .Select(filePath => 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).ToLower());

var diff = 
    dbFilePaths
    .Except(fsFilePaths)
    .Join(dbFiles, 
       filePath => filePath, 
       fdate => fdate.fname, 
      (filePath, fdate) => fdate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: returns a IEnumerable<string> ... not an IEnumerable<FileData> which is what I think he wants. 

Otherwise the intersect would have worked fine.